# Freeform Pro Custom CSV Export Order

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a way for me to export a custom column order when choosing CSV? I have one form with 27 fields of information that would be much easier to follow with a unique order. I would prefer to do the reorder on the export side for my clients needs. Solutions that use a Macro in Excel aren't ideal for this particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - the fields will export in the order they appear in the admin. Click the "Edit Field Layout" button to control which fields are shown/hidden, and drag them into the order you want them to appear.

[image: Edit Field Layout]